# How to get min and max in one sql query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

what will be the query to get min and max at once I am getting errors in this query

```
router.get('/min/:date', (req, res) => {
  const date = req.params.date;
  console.log(typeof date);
  connection.query(
    `select max(temperature) as highesttemperature; select min(temperature) as lowesttemperature from weather_data where dt=?`,
    [date],
    (err, results, field) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(results);
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: `select max(temperature) as highesttemperature, min(temperature) as lowesttemperature from weather_data where dt=?`

Comment: what will be the query to get the complete rows

Answer (score 3):

You can have both in the same query, no need for a second select:

```
select max(temperature) as highesttemperature,
min(temperature) as lowesttemperature 
from weather_data 
where dt=?
```

The error is in your first query, there is no `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MIN(temperature), MAX(temperature) FROM weather_data
```